# How to print JSON text along with other things in TSV?

Tags: json, csv, jq

```
$ jq -r '.a' <<< '{"a": 1}'
1
```

```
$ jq -M -c '.' <<< '{"a": 1}'
{"a":1}
```

I'd like to print the above two results in TSV (<TAB> is a tab character). Is there a way to do so with `jq`?

```
1<TAB>{"a":1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert the input value to a JSON text.

```
$ jq -r '[ .a, tojson ] | @tsv' <<< '{"a":1}'
1   {"a":1}
```

Comment: For safety and/or generality, consider also: `[.a, .]|map(tojson)|@tsv`